# How Can I save a Image for use in "fs.createReadStream"?

Tags: node.js, image, multer, body-parser

I'm trying to use an image that I get through my html to send it to my Node.JS

In my HTML I have this code:

`<form action="/upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="image" id="image">
      <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
    </form>`

With this I upload one image.

In my Node.JS I need use that image in this line code:

`var file = fs.createReadStream('./public/images/example.jpg')`

How can I replace `'./public/images/example.jpg'` with that image that I get through my HTML?

I am using now `multer` but I don't know how do it.

`app.post('/upload', upload.single('image'), function(req, res, next){
    // 
});`

Thanks

Comment: What's your intent? would you like to write the image data that is being submitted to your application?

Comment: @dm03514 I want to use that image because I send it to an API using fs.createReadStream

Comment: could you post your `multer` config?